# \includepdf and split by small blocks

Tags: xetex, pdfpages, books

I use includepdf so:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{Book.pdf}
```

Problem is, so book is to big (~220 pages)

I can not fold this pamphlet, because it turns out to be too thick.
I want to break into small blocks, for example 40 pages each. Then, putting it together, I'll get the book. (This is what is done in printing books in industry)

How can I do it?

Comment: Please, explain it better. With pages=1-40, you select first 40 pages, with another `\includepdf` you can get another 40 pages and so on. Is this the problem?

Comment: @Ignasi, yes, so I get an 5 separated documents. But I need one document.

Comment: But you just said you cannot fold it with 220 pages, so you need to split it into smaller documents. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: You can include as many `\includepdf` commands as you need into one `.tex` file, just place them one after the other. This way you'll get one document.

Comment: @Ignasi You mien \includepdf[pages=1-40,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{Book.pdf} \includepdf[pages=41-80,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{Book.pdf} \includepdf[pages=81-112,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{Book.pdf}
But for this I must to know total page number and manually calculate the first and last page for each block. But it's not convenient. And it's easy to make a mistake.

Comment: If this is not a solution, let me insist and explain better your problem